# How to read some property parameters dynamically inside angular 4

Tags: angular

I want to load some parameters and read it inside angular 4 app dynamically. I have tried by using property file concept and then reading these property file but it is not dynamic . For every property value change i need to redeploy my app again.

Lets say in my config file i have a property :

ip_address = 0.0.0.0 => now this IP i want to change or its getting changed as its not a static or i need to deploy the same build to multiple machines which is having different ip in all the cases i need to redeploy my app again .

So, if some property file will be there where i can configure these things or inside system variable.

Please suggest me some good approach.

Comment: How about sending an API call to backend to request its IP?

Comment: @Icycool i belive this will not work out as to call backend services i need ip and that ip itself we need to configure here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Environment configuration.
So in your case set IP in different environments.